# LPT PCIe card sometimes not detected at all in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, pci-express, device-manager, lpt

I have an [ASRock Z170 Pro4 LGA 1151](https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16813157635) motherboard, and a [RC-302E PCIe 1-Port Parallel Card](https://www.rosewill.com/product/rosewill-rc-302e-pcie-1-port-parallel-card/) connected. I am running Windows 10 Professional.

I'm having an issue with the parallel port card where sometimes it just will not show up in Device Manager at all. As in, there is no "unknown device" listed, the device is just completely absent. It doesn't matter if I hit "Scan for new hardware" or not, it doesn't show up.

Sometimes on a cold boot I will see the LPT port registered in device manager and working fine. Sometimes it is just missing altogether. Sometimes it is there at first, and disappears after a while.

Reinstalling the drivers is not the solution, as I've done this several times (and I can't install the drivers if the system thinks the device doesn't exist to begin with).

I was hoping that the solution would be similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1281317/usb-3-0-pcie-card-sometimes-not-detected-in-bios-on-one-pc-but-no-issue-on-anoth), but I have two USB PCIe cards that connect to the power supply which work fine, meanwhile the parallel port card does not connect to the power supply.

I don't know what to do to get it to just work, having to reboot several times just to see if it will work is very disruptive.

Comment: Take the card out, LIGHTLY clean the contacts with a piece of fine sandpaper or scratching the surface of the contacts until you see some fresh shine, blow out the slot, reseat the card.  If it still happens, try re-seating the card once or twice more before giving up.  You could just try re-seating the card first.

Comment: Disable PCI link power state management in Windows power settings

Comment: @LawrenceC Wow, I didn't expect this to work! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to wait to see if it sticks long-term, but in the meantime, what are the implications of disabling this setting?

Answer (score 0):

it should be plug and play, but..
Check IRQ addresses in the BIOS, update BIOS if can be updated or at least default it, try emailing  techsupport at Roswill -manufacturer may point you the right direction too.

Comment: Most BIOS don't contain IRQ settings any longer, and haven't for more than a decade now.